# Capture this in a lambda defined externally

Tags: c++, lambda, std-function

I have a class which has a `std::function` as a member variable.

```
class Animal
{
    public:
        Animal(const std::function<double(const int x)> MakeNoise) : MakeNoise(MakeNoise) {}
        void Print(const int x) { std::cout << this->MakeNoise(x) << std::endl; }
    private:
        const std::function<double(const int x)> MakeNoise;
        int a = 4;
        int b = 8;
        int c = 12;
};
```

I would like to be able to swap out the MakeNoise function without subclassing Animal by passing various lambdas.

```
const auto MakeNoise1 = [this](const int x)
{
    return a + b + x;
} 

const auto MakeNoise2 = [this](const int x)
{
    return a + b + c + x;
}
```

Is it possible to capture `this` if the definition of the function is in a different file?

Is it possible to use [&] (capture by reference) to capture x pass into `Print` ?

Lastly, is there a better way to define this class so I can swap the function in and out?

If I add `this` the compiler says `error: invalid use of ‘this’ at top level` which makes sense since the definition of the lambda is not within a class.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think this is possible to do directly. After all, the lambdas as given don't know anything about `Animal`. You can work around it by having the function's signature be
`(const Animal& animal, const int x)` instead and accessing it through `animal`.

Comment: Ideally, the design would be to just subclass Animal, but since I have so many different subclasses that are only different by the MakeNoise function, it seems silly to have so many files/classes, one for each. Your idea is interesting

Comment: @john: C++ does not enforce a "one class per file" rule. It's perfectly fine to have a `Zoo.h`.

Comment: @john I'd also note that, if you use normal functions instead of lambdas, you can declare them to be friends of Animal, which would allow access to Animal's private variables unencumbered.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a special name inside member functions. If `MakeNoise1` wants to capture `this`, it needs to be in a member of `Animal`. Your compiler told you so, and you interpreted that message corerctly.

That's not a big restriction, since `Animal::a` is `private` anyway.

You *can* define `Animal` methods in other .cpp files, but you'd still need to declare these methods in `class Animal`, so this might or might not match your larger design.

Comment: But if I have Dog, Cat, Horse, etc... I need a separate class for each, to establish that they are children of Animal. I was looking to avoid that extra code

Comment: @john: True. But from a perspective of long-term code maintenance, that is not a big price. Future coders (including yourself!) will look at `Horse` and realize "oh, just another `Animal`.". Doing anything else will suggest that inheritance was not the right solution, but that will lead the future reader to wonder _why_ not. And since there's no good answer to that question, that is going to be a waste of time. (principle of least surprise)

Answer (score 1):

If you are defining the lambda outside a member function, then no, you cannot capture `this` because there is no `this` to capture. A capture is a way to provide access to variables that are defined at the point where the lambda is defined. A capture cannot capture things that do not exist at the point of capturing.

What you want to do is provide access to variables that are defined at the point where the lambda is invoked. This is the job of parameters, as in `this->MakeNoise(this, x)` or perhaps `MakeNoise(*this, x)`. (Your `Print` wrapper can easily provide the extra parameter. In fact, adding parameters is a common motivation for writing wrapper functions.) However, I suspect that this might not be the best approach.

---

Instead of thinking about how to access `this`, think about what `MakeNoise` is supposed to do and what it needs to do that. Does it really need the entire `Animal` including private data? If so, it probably should be a member function. Bite the bullet and create a plethora of derived classes (and provide protected access to the data). Does it instead need the entire `Animal`, but only the public interface? If so, a lambda that takes both `const Animal &` and `const int` as parameters might be reasonable. Furthermore, it might be reasonable to expand the public interface to accommodate this.

Perhaps, though, you are in the case where `MakeNoise` does not really need an `Animal` so much as a few key bits of data. This is the point where you have to look at your design and your levels of abstraction. We cannot do this for you because, as is appropriate for a StackOverflow question, we do not have the complete picture. However, I can present for consideration the possibility that things other than animals can make a noise. Are your `MakeNoise` lambdas supposed to be abstract enough to not care what is making the noise? If so, you might consider adding specific data as parameters to your lambdas. Your `Print` function would become something more like the following.

```
    void Print(const int x) { std::cout << MakeNoise(x, a, b, c) << std::endl; }
```

I am assuming that `Animal` has been (appropriately) simplified for this question, and that an `Animal` object really has a lot more data than `a`, `b`, and `c`. If this assumption is false, you are in the case of needing an entire `Animal`. However, if the parameters you would need to pass to `MakeNoise` are few in comparison to the data in `Animal`, this might be a better semantic fit to your design. Might. It all comes back to making design choices that are sensible and consistent. Think abstractly while avoiding over-engineering. Keep in mind that you need to provide the same parameters to each lambda (but the various lambdas can have different captures).

Here is an example lambda that could be used for this last approach, assuming the type of `MakeNoise` – both of the data member and of the parameter to the constructor – has been updated.

```
int main()
{
    Animal cheetah{ [](int x, int a, int b, int c) -> double
                    {
                        return a + b + c + x;
                    }
                  };
    cheetah.Print(2);
}
```

*If you really want to use `const int` instead of `int`, you could. To me, it seems unnecessarily restrictive for a non-reference, but that's more style than substance.*